# Given a width of tic-tac-toe board, what is the smallest dimension such that X is guaranteed a winning strategy

Tags: mathematics, tic-tac-toe

The title says it, I'm stuck on this question.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I found the answer to what I was looking for.